# pickle.load throwing modulenotfound error with pandas 0.20

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pickle

After installing latest updates from Anaconda, I am not able to load a previously pickled file

```
Raw_Fac = pickle.load(open( "abcd.pkl", "rb"))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/....../anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2847, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-16-9588307e2ae1>", line 1, in <module>
    Raw_Fac = pickle.load(open( "abcd.pkl", "rb"))
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_bundle/pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.indexes'
```

Using -

```
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.0.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.
Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (x86_64)| (default, May 11 2017, 13:04:09) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)] on darwin
```

and

```
pandas 0.20.1
```

Comment: What about `Raw_Fac = pd.read_pickle('abcd.pkl')` ? [`read_pickle`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html)

Comment: Thank you, that works for a pandas dataframe - I will check and see if it works for a dict() item or not

Comment: it does not working for a dict() item. However, pickle.load seems to work for dict().  Thanks for the  help